# CSS delayed fade in without taking up space

Tags: css

I'm making a css animation (for starters just in Chrome, to avoid needing to retype a bunch of browser specific code a hundred times) with quite a lot going on:

First these steps simultaneously:

- Children of element fade out
- Height of element changes to fixes height
- Background color of element changes

Next step:

- Fade in a hidden element

As for what I have, all of step 1 seems to work. I'm tryng to do this all by adding a single class to the element itself, but this causes some difficulties with step 2. Because when the class is added the hidden element should be `display: block;`, but this unfortunately causes it to already take up space when the first steps are still going on.

[Here is a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sso4dc7j/). It only needs to be 1-way, so you have to re-run the fiddle to try the animation again.

This is some basic html:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="check"><svg style='width:100px;height:100px; margin: 10px auto 10px auto; z-index:20; display: block;' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><path fill='red' d='M10,17L5,12L6.41,10.58L10,14.17L17.59,6.58L19,8M12,2A10,10 0 0,0 2,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,22A10,10 0 0,0 22,12A10,10 0 0,0 12,2Z' /></svg></div>
    <div>Random content</div>
</div>
```

And a part of the css:

```
.card.done div:not(.check){
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

.check:not(.done){
    display: none;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.check svg{
    height:100px;
    margin:10px auto 10px auto;
}

.card.done div.check{
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInFromNone;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInFromNone {
    0% {
        display:none;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    50% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.card.done{
    transition: height .5s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    height: 120px !important;
}
```

Comment: That's a wow for you to do everything in CSS! `:D`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I not entirely sure I understand the problem but I think what your wanting is the SVG element to not take up space which you can do by making it position absolute

http://jsfiddle.net/p9czu73n/

```
.card.done div.check{
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:-50px;
  left:50%;
  ....
 }
```

Comment: That was quick. Didn't think about changing the positioning, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

just use:

`$(".card").css("height", "auto");`

or use add
    `height:auto;` to `.card` class

anything will fine

Comment: To be clear, the setting of the height does work (as well as backgroundColor and fading of inner div), but the second (delayed) step causes the hidden element to already take up space before that fadein kicks in.